# upload small thumbnail images from iPhone app to Amazon S3

Tags: iphone, upload, amazon-s3, response

I noticed couple thread on this already and they even provided sample code.

http://brunofuster.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/uploading-an-image-from-iphone-with-uiimagepicker-and-asihttprequests3/

But what baffled me is that - there was no response to get handled? is it because that s3 doesn't return any response? I am expecting to receive at least an URL to the image on S3, how could I get that?

Comment: Generally speaking, I think it is more likely that you didn't set up your request's delegate properly. Severs should response even when they refuse your requests

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [S3 REST object PUT](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/) documentation you will see the response that is returned from S3.

When you post to S3 you know the bucket name you are putting the image into plus you know the filename. These two pieces of information should be all you need to get a url to the image.

The documentation states that in addition to the PUT response header(s) you can see some of the common headers too.

> This implementation of the operation
>   can include the following response
>   headers in addition to the response
>   headers common to all responses. For
>   more information, see [Common Response
>   Headers](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html).

If you look at the [ASIHTTPRequest Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) support](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3) you will see how to get a response from the ASIS3ObjectRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

Tom,

If you wish to just get your S3 image url, you don't need the response information considering you already know the image name and the bucket (if there was no error).

Anyway, you can get the response from a sync request by using [request responseString|responseData].

But the right thing to do is an async call using operation queues and delegates to get the response success or error. My blog post just provided a minimal sample. I will look into that and improve the post itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already provided, you might also want to look at Amazon's recently released [AWS SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/), which includes sample code for uploading images, etc. to S3.